# remove ajax loaded data, modify the code on click and load it again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

so I have some data with scroll-loading function, it loads all of the sql table rows in divs, I'm trying to create an option to filter what it loads.

so I have the default load_more.php which loads all the rows, and another load_ph.php which loads artists type photographer only.

I tried setting the php file as a variable, then changing that variable to load_ph.php when the photographers div is clicked, but it's not working

this is what I've added

```
$( "#ph" ).click(function() {
  fetch = 'fetch_ph.php';
  $( ".feed_item" ).detach();
  load_contents(1);
})
```

full script

```
var track_page = 1; //track user scroll as page number, right now page number is 1
var loading  = false; //prevents multiple loads
var fetch = 'fetch_pages.php';
load_contents(track_page); //initial content load

$(".feed_headmk").hide();
$(".feed_headph").hide();

$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) { //if user scrolled to bottom of the page
        track_page++; //page number increment
        load_contents(track_page); //load content
    }
});
//Ajax load function
function load_contents(track_page){
    if(loading == false){
        loading = true;  //set loading flag on
        $('.loading').show(); //show loading animation
        $.post( fetch, {'page': track_page}, function(data){
            loading = false; //set loading flag off once the content is loaded
            if(data.trim().length == 0){
                //notify user if nothing to load
                $('.loading').html("");
                return;
            }
            $('.loading').hide(); //hide loading animation once data is received
            $("#feed").append(data); //append data into #results element

        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
            alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
        })
    }
}

$( "#ph" ).click(function() {
  fetch = 'fetch_ph.php';
  $( ".feed_item" ).detach();
  load_contents(1);
})
```

Comment: I would be tempted to have a single PHP script to which you send ajax requests but send a particular parameter with the request that says what items are to be processed ( ie: all data or simply artists type photographer data )

Comment: that'd be great, but how can I do it? total newb here

Comment: you appear to have the bulk of what i suggested in place already. The ajax function sends a parameter `page` - use that POST parameter in the php script - either using a `switch` statement or an `if()else()` statement to determine what is processed